# What is the difference between varchar and text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

What is the difference between data types **var char** and **text** in database design?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-types.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [varchar vs text - MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739172/varchar-vs-text-mysql)

Comment: @Wickramaranga -- that particular Q&A is a shambles of multiple questions and dubious answers.  I added [_my own answer_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39059399/1766831), which does address the current question.

Comment: @juergend You should post this as an answer, with a bit of expanded commentary as well as just the link.

Comment: Removed redundancies

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is than TEXT has a fixed max size of 2¹⁶-1 = 65535 characters.
VARCHAR has a variable max size M up to M = 2¹⁶-1.

Comment: Close -- The limit for `TEXT` is in _bytes_; `VARCHAR` is in _characters_.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few differences between `VARCHAR` and `TEXT`.  Most are not really important.

Summary of `*TEXT`, `CHAR`, and `VARCHAR`:

- Never use `TINYTEXT`.
- Almost never use `CHAR` -- it is fixed length; each character is the max length of the `CHARACTER SET` (eg, 4 bytes/character for utf8mb4).
- With `CHAR`, use `CHARACTER SET ascii` unless you know otherwise.
- `VARCHAR(n)` will truncate at n *characters*; `TEXT` will truncate at some number of *bytes*.  (But, do you want truncation?)
- `*TEXT` *may* slow down complex `SELECTs` due to how temp tables are handled.

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR column can be given with any size, but it is limited by the maximum size of a single row of data (including all columns), which is 64KB (2¹⁶-1) .TEXT columns do not add to the maximum row size, because the actual text is not stored with the rest of the row.