# How are large text fields stored in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, testing, varchar

For example, this field I am writing in now can holds a lot of text.  I'm assuming this is a mySQL VARCHAR or TEXT field but this is just a guess.  According to [MySQL: Large VARCHAR vs. TEXT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text) TEXT should be used.  Where is the line for switching from VARHCAR to TEXT.  I'm looking for something more concrete then the link I posted.

I of course want to be able to search the text and edit it.

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer?  Size is **not** the consideration that's identified.  Off-the-table vs. in-the-table is the consideration.  What part of the accepted answer confuses you?  Please  **update** the question with specific references to the accepted answer that you find confusing or incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VARCHAR is limited to 255 characters in all mysql versions <= 5.0.3

There are various sizes of TEXT fields as well, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT.

You can find more details here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html

I would strongly suggest defaulting to text or larger for what you're proposing.

Comment: varchar is limited to 64k for more recent versions, limited by rowsize. Row size is limited to 64k, not including any blobs.