# VARCHAR vs TEXT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, datafield

I have two fields: one to store an `excerpt` with a max size of 500 characters, and another to store a `description` with a max size of 10,000 characters.

What data types should I use, `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`? And why?

After MySQL 5.0.3 VARCHAR accepts ~65000 characters. But this does not tell why I should use one type and or the other.

I'm reasoning that I should use `VARCHAR` for the excerpt because I can assign a size limit, and `TEXT` for the `description` field as it's larger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Large VARCHAR vs. TEXT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A long `VARCHAR` is stored in the same manner as a `TEXT`/`BLOB` field in `InnoDB` (which I assume you're using for transactionality, referential integrity and crash recovery, right?) - that is, externally to the rest of the table on disk (which may require another disk read to retrieve).

> From storage prospective BLOB, TEXT as
>   well as long VARCHAR are handled same
>   way by Innodb. This is why Innodb
>   manual calls it “long columns” rather
>   than BLOBs.

[source](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/)

Unless you need to index these columns (in which case `VARCHAR` is much faster) there is no reason to use `VARCHAR` over `TEXT` for long fields - there are some engine specific optimisations in `MySQL` to tune the data retrieval according to length, and you should use the correct column type to take advantage of these.

In case you're using `MyISAM` an in-depth discussion on the topic is [here](http://nicj.net/2011/01/20/mysql-text-vs-varchar-performance).

Comment: @Andy, this is interesting because according to idstam, above, you can do full text indexing on VARCHAR. He cited this article, which I'm yet to read: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Getting-Started-With-MySQLs-Full-Text-Search-Capabilities/1/

Comment: Fulltext supported on both column types for `MyISAM` anyway: `Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @Andy, thanks. I had no idea. So if I wanted to use a Full-text index to allow my users to search `description` fields, I have to convert my table to `MyISAM`? Also, if I understood you correctly, LONG `VARCHAR`, or above `255` characters, is going to behave the same way as `TEXT` and `BLOB`?

Comment: Table conversion has its own disadvantages. Normalising the `description` field to its own `MyISAM` table and joining on it will allow simultaneous use of the robust features of `InnoDB` and the single desirable feature of `MyISAM` :)

Comment: @Andy, interesting approach. So much to think about. Everything was really simple until about a15 minutes ago! :) Thank you!

Comment: @Andy, PS: when does `VARCHAR` become considered `LONG VARCHAR`? Is there a character threshold?

Comment: It should be clarified what is specifically meant by "long fields" - for string lengths less than or equal to 255, `VARCHAR` consumes one byte less of overhead.

Answer (score 11):

One difference between `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` is that you can declare a `DEFAULT` clause for a `VARCHAR` column, but not for a `TEXT` column.

@Andy is correct that InnoDB stores both `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` in the same way internally.

`FULLTEXT` indexes are supported on both `VARCHAR` and `TEXT`. Prior to 5.6, you must use MyISAM to get that type of index. In MySQL 5.6, it finally supports `FULLTEXT` in InnoDB. Though you should test it carefully, because it seems to [return different results](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/03/04/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-2-the-queries/) than the implementation in MyISAM.

However, [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is faster and richer in features than either implementation in MySQL.  See my overview in [Full-Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

@Mohammed asked:

> when does `VARCHAR` become considered `LONG VARCHAR`? Is there a character threshold?

If you declare a length of up to 255 bytes, it can encode the length of a given string using one byte. If you declare the column max length over 255 bytes, it will use two bytes to encode the length.

You can declare a column as `LONG VARCHAR`, but this is really just an alias for [MEDIUMTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html).

```
mysql> create table test ( l long varchar);

mysql> show create table test\G

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `l` mediumtext
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 8):

If your content fits in a varchar column then use varchar.

Varchar data is stored in each row. Text data is stored as blobs outside of the table.

According to [this test](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105964), varchar is about three times faster than text.

Comment: interesting, thank you for that. Can VARCHAR columns be full-text indexed for search purposes?

Comment: Yes, according to this: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Getting-Started-With-MySQLs-Full-Text-Search-Capabilities/1/