# How do I store a link inside mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a website with a database that works as planned, but I want to create a field that can hold a link inside the database. Some tips about how I can do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: varchar or Text will be okay for your case.

Comment: Tip: Put some effort into it and start looking around Stack/Google, there's a ton of stuff out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a link in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266654/how-to-save-a-link-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I would store the link in a field of type `text`. However, you could use `VARCHAR`. There may be performance improvements in choosing to go with `VARCHAR` over `text`. See here for more info: [MySQL: Large VARCHAR vs. TEXT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text)