# From sqlite syntax to mysql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm having some troubles moving from sqlite syntax to mysql syntax. Does anybody know a ressource showing the basic syntax in sqlite and its equivalent in mysql ?

In my particular case, I want to transform this sqlite code into mysql one:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;


CREATE TABLE post (
  a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  b TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  c TEXT NOT NULL,
  d TEXT NOT NULL,
  e TEXT NOT NULL,
  f TEXT NOT NULL,
  g TEXT NOT NULL,
  h TEXT NOT NULL,
  i TEXT,
  j TEXT NOT NULL,
  k TEXT,
  l TEXT NOT NULL,
  m TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

For the moment, I did that:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;

```
CREATE TABLE post (
  a INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  b CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  c TEXT NOT NULL,
  d TEXT NOT NULL,
  e TEXT NOT NULL,
  f TEXT NOT NULL,
  g TEXT NOT NULL,
  h TEXT NOT NULL,
  i TEXT,
  j TEXT NOT NULL,
  k TEXT,
  l TEXT NOT NULL,
  m TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

But I got errors with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and TEXT.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the only change that you have to do is to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead of SQLite's `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword and your statement will work fine in MySql too.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9e97037a0c1b029add1dd607171a0437).

But you'd better not use MySql's [`TEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) data type.
SQLite has only 1 data type for storing strings and this is the `TEXT` data type.
On the other hand MySql supports [`VARCHAR` and `CHAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) data types for storing string values.
If a column does not hold really long strings, then the preferred data type is `VARCHAR` and not `TEXT`.
You can find more about the differences of the 2 data types in these threads:

- [VARCHAR vs TEXT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404628/varchar-vs-text-in-mysql)
- [Difference between VARCHAR and TEXT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300821/difference-between-varchar-and-text-in-mysql)

So a statement that would make sense is:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
  a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  b TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  c VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  d VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  e VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  f VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  g VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  h VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  i VARCHAR(10),
  j VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  k VARCHAR(10),
  l VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  m VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

You may replace the number `10` in `VARCHAR(10)` with max expected length for each of the columns.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL syntax(translated with https://www.jooq.org/translate/):

```
drop table if exists post;
create table post (
  a int not null auto_increment,
  b timestamp not null default current_timestamp(),
  c text not null,
  d text not null,
  e text not null,
  f text not null,
  g text not null,
  h text not null,
  i text,
  j text not null,
  k text,
  l text not null,
  m text not null,
  primary key (a)
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a41c4d7bf53edba7790457c940de1907)**