# Storing Sentence in Database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sentence

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to be able to store a sentence in a MySQL database after being sent from an Android app. I have a field in my app that allows a user to enter a description (the sentence) and when they press send all of their personal information along with the description is sent to a db. I have all of the personal data sending and receiving, but the sentence is not working. Is there a way to do this? I tried using a BLOB, but it just shows up as `[BLOB-4B]` in the table. I'm a noob so be gentle. Thanks!

Comment: I like how all the personal information goes straight into a database administered by a self-declared "noob".

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android but I see no obstacle to storing a `String` in MySQL. Is it possible to use a simple `VARCHAR`? From my understanding, `BLOB`s are generally used for binary data. The `[BLOB-4B]` you're getting is most likely a `toString` value.

Comment: Blobs are for binary, you want a [text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) column.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `VARCHAR(num)` where `num` is the maximum length of your sentence.

[Help for VARCHAR is here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

[Here is a question from SO regarding whether to choose Text or Varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text)

Comment: I tried doing that, but if the description is a sentence, the table does not receive any data. If I use one word instead, the database will receive everything.

Comment: Post your code - `varchar` can store strings with spaces in them !

Comment: @Alex: How is your sentence stored in Java? Also, how are you mapping it to the MySQL DB?

Comment: Well I have an EditText that is converted to a string, then I use HttpPost to send it to a PHP script which adds it to the table. I have tried varchar, blob, text, etc., but nothing seems to work. I just tried text, but if I have more than one word, nothing gets added to the db. If I have just one word (for the description, where I want to be able to enter a sentence), everything is added to the db.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. I tried adding another word to the first name field (with a space) and it receives it just fine. They both have the same attributes, except the edittext in the Android app is a text box. Could there be problems converting the content of the text box to a string?

Comment: @Alex again - post your Java code ... without that we are guessing !

Answer (score 0):

Use the [TEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) datatype. VARCHAR, CLOB (character large object), etc all have TEXT affinity in sqlite v3 (since you have the question tagged with Android).

Comment: oops, i didnt see the question properly. my bad! i saw the android tag and assumed sqlite.