# What is the next best thing after VARCHAR(255)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 2 million records in it.
I have a field called message which is setup as varchar(160) and I need something bigger that varchar(255) because I need to be able to store about 500 characters in it, what is the next best datatype to use without increasing the size of the db drastically?

thanks

Answer (score 11):

[Starting with MySQL 5.0.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html), you can simply use `VARCHAR(500)`.

> M represents the maximum column length in characters. In MySQL 5.0, the range of M is 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in MySQL 5.0.3 and later.

Comment: In other words, the next largest is `VARCHAR(256)`. :)

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yes! I was so tempted to write that in the answer, but in the end decided to simply quote from the manual.

Comment: great! I miss it, doubting it for a long time~

Answer (score 3):

If you're on 5.0.3 or later a varchar can be 65535 characters.

[11.4.1. The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

[MySQL: Large VARCHAR vs. TEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TEXT` then *Run* [PROCEDURE ANALYSE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/procedure-analyse.html)

> that suggests optimal data types for each column that may help reduce table sizes.