# When to use TEXT in mysql instead of VARCHAR

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: Large VARCHAR vs. TEXT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text)

Since `VARCHAR` can have 65k bytes now, when then should `TEXT` be used instead of `VARCHAR`?

Comment: When you need more than 65k characters. :)

Comment: That should be 65k *bytes*, not characters, I think

Comment: Oh, yes. 65k bytes. Updated my question.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A long `VARCHAR` is stored in the same manner as a `TEXT`/`BLOB` field in `InnoDB`.

> From storage prospective BLOB, TEXT as
>   well as long VARCHAR are handled same
>   way by Innodb. This is why Innodb
>   manual calls it “long columns” rather
>   than BLOBs.

[source](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/)

Unless you need to index these columns (in which case `VARCHAR` is much faster) there is no reason to use `VARCHAR` over `TEXT` for long fields - there are some engine specific optimisations in `MySQL` to tune the data retrieval according to length, and you should use the correct column type to take advantage of these.

In case you're using `MyISAM` an in-depth discussion on the topic is [here](http://nicj.net/2011/01/20/mysql-text-vs-varchar-performance).

---

`TEXT` and `BLOB` are stored off the table with the table just having a pointer to the location of the actual storage.

`VARCHAR` is stored inline with the table. `VARCHAR` is faster when the size is reasonable.

According to [this test](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105964), `VARCHAR` is about thrice as fast as text.

Comment: Define "long field".

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski > 768 bytes (see the link Lion posted)

Comment: One correction for InnoDB: TEXT and BLOB are stored off the table in InnoDB only if "long" (> 768 bytes), and only the tail is stored off table (similar to VARCHAR). The real difference is the maximum lengths differ, and with VARCHAR you must supply a max length (enforces along with the system limit of 65k).

Comment: ah, should've known datatype affects performance

Comment: _Update_:  Since this Answer was written, more `ROW_FORMATs` have been created in InnoDB, and the 767 limit has grown to about 3K.  Bottom line: Past a 'few' KB, `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` are handled identically.

Answer (score 4):

Text should be used for really long strings of indeterminate length.  Also, queries that return TEXT fields tend to be much slower than their VARCHAR counterparts.

Comment: In my database, I have a column named Description. Should the datatype be a VARCHAR or TEXT? I am not sure how long the description data is going to be, but I am planning to put a word count limit on the front end so it will have max length.