# Varchar or Text Data Types for strings length up to few thousands of chars

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I have a small social networking website, with posts and comments. 
I decided to let users create posts with any number of charس they want, and I think the best Datatype for storing such things is **Text**.
But for comments, in most cases users write only one or a few lines of text.  That's why I think that I have to limit comment string length to something like 3000 or even 6000 chars maximum.
So, what Datatype should I use for my comments ?
**Varchar** or **Text**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various places where `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` do or do not differ.  Some things I say:

- If the maximum length is more than 512 *characters*, go with `TEXT`.
- Never use `TINYTEXT` -- it has only negatives relative to `VARCHAR(255)`.
- Don't use `VARCHAR(255)`; pick a reasonable max instead of 255.  (This is a minor optimization relating to temp table in complex queries.)
- Use `CHAR` only for things that are truly fixed length.  In almost all such case, tack on `CHARACTER SET ascii` (or latin1).  (Else it will take more space than you expect.
- Use `CHARACTER SET ut8mb4`.  (Exceptions are becoming more an more rare.)

(Sorry, I digress.  Back on topic...)

I indexing, in layout of InnoDB rows (there are 4 different `ROW_FORMATs`), etc, `VARCHAR(513)` will be essentially indistinguishable from `TEXT`.

One of the few arguments for `VARCHAR` is that it limits the store to the length given.  But how often is that important?

Answer (score 2):

Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535, which would seem big enough to handle your user's expected comment length.

The four TEXT types are TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT. The maximum amount of data that can be stored for each data type is approximately:

TINYTEXT 256 bytes

TEXT 65,535 bytes ~64kb

MEDIUMTEXT 16,777,215 bytes ~16MB

LONGTEXT 4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB

See also [When to use TEXT in mysql instead of VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441823/when-to-use-text-in-mysql-instead-of-varchar)

Comment: Thnx, in the link source author write this : "VARCHAR is stored inline with the table. VARCHAR is faster when the size is reasonable.", so is varchar(3000) considered  reasonable size ?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the four type of TEXT available [TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT] depending on your requirements. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html