# Optimal way to store 1000+ (30-50 KB) texts in a MySQL table with outer .TXT files?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I would like to store 1000+ records in a table. It has got:

ID : auto increment INT
title  : varchar (20)
author_ID : INT
timestamp : unsigned INT
text : TEXT (this is the problem)
(+tags and categories)

The "text" field has to store about 30-50 KByte texts. But I don't want to search in this field, only in the other ones. Is it a good idea, to store these big texts in .TXT files? Will the database queries be faster?

Comment: You can better save the TEXT column(s) in a separated table. And join the table when you need the TEXT column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TEXT and BLOB are stored off the table.

There is only a pointer to the location of the actual storage. I don't think that you have to worry too much, especially if you have only around 1 thousand records.

Anyway, referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441823/when-to-use-text-in-mysql-instead-of-varchar), if your data is always < 65 KByte, you can think about using VARCHAR.

It seems that it will have better performances.

More info in the linked Q&A.

Comment: That post is somewhat out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `MEDIUMTEXT` because some day your 30-50K will grow to 70K.  `VARCHAR` won't go that far

The way InnoDB structures things, there is rarely any not to keep text columns in the database.  (Images are another matter.)

There is a pitfall wherein you `JOIN` two tables, then pare the resultset down with `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT` -- If you are carrying big text columns through the temp tables, this can be a performance problem.