# How to determine Which type is optimal for a 1-2 words column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column which consist of records of one to two words. I'm not sure whether I should set it to VARCHAR, TEXT or something else.

While researching about this I learned that [there's a difference in the way those are stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text), but I can't determine which is more suitable for this kind of content.

**What factors should I consider when picking the type for this kind of column?**

Comment: I've rephrased the question, hope it's a bit more constructive now

Comment: About the downvote and close-votes - I'd be happy to get a small explanation about why this question isn't good enough and/or some improvement suggestions

Comment: This is a very design-centric question, not the technical questions that SO caters for. As a rule of thumb, it only belongs on SO if you are having a problem with a piece of code. Design questions generally find a better response over at http://programmers.stackExchange.com, but because it's a database question, you should try http://dba.stackexchange.com. Additionally, it's a very broad question which is quite hard to answer. It would be better to describe the specifics of your situation, including the performance profile you want, rather than asking for general advice.

Comment: @Tragedian thanks you, this is exactly what I needed. Wish I could 'accept' you comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the length of the words, but if you're talking about 15 characters per word max, I'd go with a `VARCHAR(45)`.

Answer (score 0):

Longtext is the only choice for sure.
Varchar is not an option - which 2 words you can store using 255 characters? it's not enough even for one