# Persist Text SQL Type via ORMLite (not LONGVARCHAR)

Tags: mysql, ormlite, sqldatatypes

Using DataType.LONG_STRING attribute value Persisted as SQL type LONGVARCHAR which handles longer strings.

However, i want to map the field to SQL type TEXT .

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_STRING)
String comment;
```

Since there is a [difference between LONGVARCHAR and TEXT SQL Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text),  DataType.LONG_STRING value does not solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So by default the `LONG_STRING` type is supposed to generate `TEXT` as the schema -- Postgres and MySQL do for example.  What database type are you using?  Derby generates `LONG VARCHAR`, Hsqldb `LONGVARCHAR`, and Oracle `LONG`.  I think this was for compatibility reasons.

There a couple of ways that you can override the schema that [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) produces.  The easiest is to define the column yourself with the [`columnDefinition` part of the `@DatabaseField`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#columnDefinition%28%29):

```
@DatabaseField(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
String comment;
```

If you are making more complex changes to the database compability code, you can also override the `DatabaseType` you are using.  In this case you can override the `appendLongStringType(...)` method to produce a different schema.  I'd override `DerbyDatabaseType` or whatever database you are using and then add something like:

```
@Override
protected void appendLongStringType(StringBuilder sb, FieldType fieldType,
    int fieldWidth) {
    sb.append("TEXT");
}
```

Comment: Well I'm not a mind reader so I didn't know.  MySQL should generated `TEXT` for `DataType.LONG_STRING`.  I've just tested it and it does.  What version of ORMLite are you using?  Is it possibly using the wrong database type @AbdennourToumi?

Comment: i use the last =>4.45 .thanks again for this tracking.But,if DataType.LONG_STRING generates TEXT what about LONGVARCHAR

Comment: Well, you change the `columnDefinition` field above.  Right @AbdennourToumi?