# Storing checkbox values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

So one of my columns in my table has values like this

`a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Subbed";i:1;s:6:"Dubbed";}`

Right now it's stored as `longtext` and I've heard that `varchar` is faster than `longtext` if you're going to query it often.

So I have two questions, can values like this be stored as `varchar` and how do I retrieve these values as an array in php like `["Subbed, "Dubbed"]`.

How do I insert values like this if I have something like `["Subbed", "Dubbed"]` and I want `a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Subbed";i:1;s:6:"Dubbed";}` .

Finally, is this something like a stringified array?

Comment: you should look at db normalisation, this is not the ideal storage strategy

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't doing this in a [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) way? You are violating [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) with this structure which typically is not good.

Comment: How does your title match your question?

Comment: Your first problem is that your data is not held correctly.  You should not have multiple values saved in a single column.  They should each have their own.  As far as the difference between LONGTEXT and VARCHAR, yeah, LONGTEXT is a really bad idea.

Comment: Also, in this stage, I wouldn't worry about the field type. I don't think the field type shouldn't matter *that* much. Also note that varchar has serious limits. The total record size in MySQL can be 65535 bytes at most, which is about 21000 characters if you have a UTF-8 VARCHAR field. This is total per record, so all fields combined. LONGTEXT is stored separately and doesn't have this limit.

Comment: Guys this is how wordpress stores all its `meta_values`, as `longtext`. But I have thousands of entries stored like this. So sure i'll go ahead and normalize it. But another question is for every checkbox I have I'll have to create a `pivot table` and a separate table for the checkbox options. Seems like a hassle.

Comment: well you could of saved us both some time by tagging it with wordpress :(

Comment: @dagon I am exporting this out of wordpress and will be creating a new structure with post types have their own tables and no post meta table. What I am wondering is if it's actually a good idea to go about the whole normalization for each and every checkbox I have for a post type.

Comment: sigh, can i have my 5 minute back please

Comment: @Dagon I don't see why wordpress changes anything. My questions are not affected, they have no correlation with the fact that the DB is on WordPress. I am moving away from WordPress and I am exporting all of the data and remodeling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See this question: [MySQL: Large VARCHAR vs. TEXT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text)
2. It's the format used by  serialization functions in php! You get to learn stuff every day. Check the PHP documentation.

Comment: write a parser !?!? lol `serialize` was used so um use `unserialize` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the serialization function of PHP, thank you for the link, and glad I could make you laugh...

Comment: 7k rep and you have never encountered one of the basic php functions come on dude :-)

Comment: I never had to use them. And as you may see, my rep isn't solely based on php. Hopefully I'll get a badge for it some day though, I'm getting there with everyone's help.

Comment: Thanks! I must admit though that this looked slightly familiar :)

Comment: So serialize will return `string` in which case I should be able to use varchar. Main question is if it's worth normalizing.

Comment: I don't understand that question: it seemed that you had your db set that way, so how would you keep it working with your cms (wordpress?) If you change the db structure?

Comment: "Main question is if it's worth normalizing. " - almost always YES

Comment: @didierc I am not going to be using wordpress any more. I am taking the data and remodeling it.

Comment: Might need to filter data by choices.

Comment: So you want to export that data, and feed it to another CMS?

Comment: Removed all the comment material. I think you should extract that data and save it as csv for instance. Then try to design a db which works with what you have. If the format is fixed, you certainly can model it into a normalized db.