# To use VARCHAR(1000) or LONGTEXT?

Tags: mysql

What is the difference in using a very large `VARCHAR` field or using a `LONGTEXT` field? At which point, would it be advantageous to start using a `LONGTEXT` over `VARCHAR`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text check this links and this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/a/13182846/552116

Answer (score 1):

Once you are past about 512 characters, there is no practical difference between `VARCHAR` and `TEXT`.  (`TEXT` gives you a max of 64K.)