# What's the correct way to store a list in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to make a list of numbers structure in MySQL (phpMyAdmin), I was thinking about storing it as a varchar with commas between all the numbers, and then when I want to fetch them I just split them, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

~Sorry if I wasn't clear, my English isn't that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the length of the number, probably you can use just use TEXT data type.

Comment: So, TEXT data type can store more characters?

Comment: Yes. BLOB, TEXT L + 2 bytes, where L < 2 power 16

Comment: Maybe you should use VARCHAR instead of TEXT/BLOB because of how values are stored as explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text

Answer (score 0):

with explode function you can separate your data with specified character and store into array

ex.

```
$demo = '1,2,3,4';
$data = explode(',',$demo);
```

this with store 1,2,3,4 separately in data array

Comment: I get it, so I store the data as TEXT and then just explode it.

Comment: yea, saving data as varchar or text doesn't matter