# Best practices and data types for relative short strings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In most projects I've worked on, stuff like usernames are stored as the default VARCHAR(45). I've been under the mistaken impression that the (45) was just a display limit, but [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) indicate that it's the maximum number of characters you want to store.

This seems kind of annoying to me. Does this mean that you have to guess at the high end and implement some kind of check to warn your user every time a value for that field is provided? Do most devs simply declare something like VARCHAR(10000)?

Another field I have is for a short summary. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text) gives some examples of when to use VARCHAR (username) vs TEXT (messages). The field I'm looking at could have strings in the 300-2000 character range by my best guess. Is this still suitable for VARCHAR? What's the best way to protect or warn if it tries to store something too large?

Comment: `varchar` is limited to 255 characters

Comment: @Bhawin the max limit of varchar in MySQL is 65,535 bytes (even v5.5 had that limit)

Comment: @Shadow - that means minimal 21.150 Chars when UTF8 is used (3 Bytes per CHAR)

Answer (score 0):

Varchar datatype is suitable for holding text in the 300-2000 character range, since it can hold [up to 65,535 bytes of data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) (remember, if you use multi-byte character set, such as utf8, then the actual byte length is more than the character length).

What you need to consider is the overall record size limit of MySQL (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) when you choose between `varchar` and any `text` fields:

- The entire byte length of a `varchar` field counts towards the record size limit
- For `text` fields only a table engine dependent part is stored within the record, which counts toward the overall record limit. The rest is stored somewhere else (again, it is table engine dependent).

So, if you need to store several 2k character long fields in  record, then you may hit the max record size limit and be forced to use `text`. Otherwise, you can use `varchar`.

And what's the best way to protect or warn if it tries to store something too large? Well, if you prevent users from entering more characters than allowed is a good start. Check out what SO does when you type a comment, it is quite a good example of restricting the length of text that can be typed. But it all depends on your exact application and audience.