# October CMS - Data too long for column 'content' at row 1

Tags: mysql, laravel, octobercms

I have an error saving a field to the database, which is giving me the error: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'content' at row 1.

However the field in the database is set to  Type: String, length 191. Which i believe translates to varchar.

Anybody else had this?

Comment: use text field for the datatype

Comment: but it has html...

Comment: `$table->text('content');`

Comment: what is wrong with it, i mean having HTML in the input

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It seems it was a simple change of string to text.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **NOT** store a posts or pages content (something that contains a lot of text/html) as `String`.

Instead use `TEXT` for the MySQL column type, which allows to enter enough characters in there.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182846/2693543

copied from above answer

> VARCHAR(X) Case: user name, email, country, subject, password
>
> TEXT Case: messages, emails, comments, formatted text, html, code,
>   images, links
>
> MEDIUMTEXT Case: large json bodies, short to medium length books, csv
>   strings
>
> LONGTEXT Case: textbooks, programs, years of logs files, harry potter
>   and the goblet of fire, scientific research logging

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your migration file and it will change your column data type and then you can save html content into it without any problem.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('the_table_name', function () {
        $table->longText('columnName')->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('the_table_name');
}
```